many to many relationship sqlalchemy in fastapi
I'm trying to create many to many relationships using sqlalchemy in fastapi but I got this error when I'm trying to add associations between student_id=1 and course_id=2:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: student_course.student_id, student_course.course_id [SQL: INSERT INTO student_course (student_id, course_id) VALUES (?, ?)] [parameters: [(1, 2), (1, 2)]]
I try it with SQLite3 and PostgreSQL and get almost the same error.
my codes look like this:
models.py:
student_course = Table("student_course", Base.metadata,
                       Column("student_id", Integer, ForeignKey("students.id"), primary_key=True),
                       Column("course_id", Integer, ForeignKey("courses.id"), primary_key=True))

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = "students"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(String, index=True)
    lastname = Column(String, index=True)
    average = Column(Float, index=True)
    graduated = Column(Boolean, default=False)

    courses = relationship("Course",secondary=student_course,back_populates="students")

class Course(Base):
    __tablename__ = "courses"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    unit = Column(Integer, index=True)

    students = relationship("Student",secondary=student_course,back_populates="courses")

schema.py:
class CourseBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    unit: int


class CourseCreate(CourseBase):
    pass


class Course(CourseBase):
    id: int
    students: list["Student"] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class StudentBase(BaseModel):
    firstname: str
    lastname: str


class StudentCreate(StudentBase):
    average: float
    graduated: bool


class Student(StudentBase):
    id: int
    courses: list[Course] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

crud.py:
def add_course_to_student(db: Session, student_id: int, course_id: int):
    student = db.query(models.Student).get(student_id)
    course = db.query(models.Course).get(course_id)
    
    student.courses.append(course)
    course.students.append(student)
    db.commit()


Thanks to @couteau I change crud.py to:
def add_course_to_student(db: Session, student_id: int, course_id: int):
    student = db.query(models.Student).get(student_id)
    course = db.query(models.Course).get(course_id)
    
    student.courses.append(course)
    db.commit()

The process goes without any error, but when I want to read my Students or Courses error occurs.
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 1 validation errors: {'type': 'recursion_loop', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'courses', 0, 'students', 0), 'msg': 'Recursion error - cyclic reference detected', 'input': <app.models.Student object at 0x0000024C871FD760>, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/recursion_loop'}
I figured out it is because of response_model. I don't know how to respond to it in a correct format that returns the relationships without error.
in main.py:
@app.get("/students/", response_model=list[schemas.Student])
def read_students(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    students = crud.get_students(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return students

in case you need get_students in crud.py:
def get_students(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Student).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


You’re adding the relationship twice by adding the student to the course and the course to the student. You only need to do one of those.

@couteau Thanks, I have updated my question. I would be grateful if you could help me again.

https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/many-to-many-relationships-in-fastapi/

Problem is schemas.Student refers to schemas.Course which refers to schemas.Student. It is called recursion.
As a solution I can provide you this:
class Student(StudentBase):
    id: int

class Course(CourseBase):
    id: int

class StudentWithCourses(Student):
    courses: list[Course] = []

class CourseWithStudents(Course):
    students: list[Student] = []

@app.get("/students/", response_model=list[StudentWithCourses])
def read_students(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    students = crud.get_students(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return students

